# Deploy or undeploy app as a non-admin user

Tags: payara

On Payara v5.184

Is it possible to create a non-admin user in Payara that can manage apps? i.e. a non-admin user `foo` would be able to run just the below commands:

```
asadmin undeploy <app>
asadmin deploy <app> 
asadmin list-applications
```

What would be the commands to create `foo` user and enable the above on this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible but there is a request for this feature:

https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1600

A possible workaround would be to wrap your adminconsole calls into a bash-script and create a user with the corresponding permission.